# Put set of values from a json string into the form using view model in extjs5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm working on my first extjs (5) application and I have two main questions, one about the structure and another one is a technical question. My application is an admin panel. I have a database table with key-value-pairs with settings like site name, keywords, meta description and so on. Now I want to create a form, where user can edit these options. My problem now is that I can't get these options displayed in the form.

Here is the model for options:

```
Ext.define('Wp.model.Option', {
    extend: 'Wp.model.Base',
    idProperty: 'name',

    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

I have the following view:

```
Ext.define('Wp.view.settings.BasicSettings', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'wp-basic-settings',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    title: 'Grundeinstellungen',
    cls: 'content-container',

    requires: [
        'Wp.view.settings.BasicSettingsModel'
    ],

    viewModel: 'basic-settings',

    fieldDefaults: {
        labelWidth: 250,
        width: '100%'
    },

    items: [{
        bind: '{siteName}',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        allowBlank: false

    },{
        bind: '{lang}',
        fieldLabel: 'Lokalisierung',
        allowBlank: false

    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Speichern',
        formBind: true,
        listeners: {
        }
    }]
});
```

If I understand MVVC correctly, the right solution would be to create a view model, that will get set of options of type Wp.model.Option and "pass" it to the view.

I tried different view models, but I can't get it working.

```
Ext.define('Wp.view.settings.BasicSettingsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.basic-settings',

    requires: [
        'Wp.model.Option'
    ],

    stores: {
        data: {
            model: 'Wp.model.Option',
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url: 'BasicSettings.json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            },
            autoLoad: true
        }
    },

    formulas: {
        siteName: function (get) {
            return get('data')[0].value;
        },

        lang: function (get) {
            return get('data')[1].value;
        }
    }
});
```

The answer, that I get from the server is something like this:

```
{"data":[{"name":"siteName","value":"Some site name"},{"name":"lang","value":"en"}]}
```

(I tried different versions, with root element and rootProperty, without it, with success property, I can change the format - it isn't the problem).

The result is always the same: empty fields. The problem seems to be the asynchronous query, because it works just fine with memory store. But I don't know how I can "wait" for the query and get the values from the json then, where I can put something like "load" listener.

I also tried "links:" and "reference" instead of "stores:" but I get then [object Object] in the fields and don't know, what I can to do with that.

Is my try to solve my problem at least correct? How can I achieve the correct displaying of the stuff from the json string in my form?

PS: I've read in these two days a lot of stuff with similar questions on StackOverflow and on the sencha forum, but I couldn't really use suggested solutions for my problem, so sorry, if I don't understand something. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have the recordProperty too. Otherwise it asumes "records" instead of "data". So recordProperty: "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way that your JSON is formed is whats causing you some issues. A form expects to be able to bind directly to a named field, in your case name / value, not the actual values of the field.

To be able to load the data into a form and edit / save it, it would be much easier if your JSON was in this kind of format:

```
{
   "siteName": "some sites name",
   "lang": "en" 
}
```

To work with the data in the format that you have provided above I think a Editable grid would be more appropriate and easier to use:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('WpOption', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty: 'name',

            fields: [
                {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
                {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
            ]
        });

        var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            // store configs
            storeId: 'myStore',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/data/data5.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            },

            model: "WpOption",
            listeners: {
                "load": function() {
                    console.log(this.getCount());
                }
            }

        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Testing',
            store: store,
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'value', flex: 1,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                }
            ],
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1
            },
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});

// data/data5.json - I added an ID field, which would be needed for editing

{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "siteName",
            "value": "Some site name"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "lang",
            "value": "en"
        }
    ]
}
```

The below links should be good reading for your question:

- [Ext.grid.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel)
- [Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditiing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing)
- [Ext.data.JsonStore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore)
- [Ext.form.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel)

Good luck with the project, If I've missed anything let me know in the comments and I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks. I haven't completely adopted your solution, but thanks to your answer I found, that extjs provides propertyGrid and it is, what I actually was looking for. I will need forms for other things, like user editing. Let's see if I'll rid of the forms then.